# Yaml Template expression returns false

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, boolean

In the following example, Azure DevOps template expression returns always "False", even if the parameter is true.
Why ?

**Main.yml :**

```
trigger: none
pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
  vmImage: windows-latest

variables:
  - name: myVar
    value: true

steps:
- checkout: none
- powershell: |
      Write-Host "myVar = $(myVar)" # Display true
- template: TestJppTemplate.yml
  parameters:
    myParam: $(myVar)
- powershell: |
      Write-Host "myVar = $(myVar)" # Display true
```

**TestJppTemplate.yml :**

```
parameters:
  - name: myParam
    type: string

steps:
- powershell: |
    Write-Host "myParam: ${{parameters.myParam}}" # Display true
    Write-Host "expression1: ${{eq(parameters.myParam, 'True')}}" # Display False
    Write-Host "expression2: ${{eq(parameters.myParam, 'true')}}" # Display False
    Write-Host "expression3: ${{eq(lower(parameters.myParam), 'true')}}" # Display False
    Write-Host "expression4: ${{eq(parameters.myParam, true)}}" # Display False
    Write-Host "expression5: ${{eq(parameters.myParam, True)}}" # Display False
```

Answer (score 0):

As part of an [expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops), you may access variables using one of two syntaxes:

Index syntax: variables['MyVar']
Property dereference syntax: variables.MyVar

If you want to use the parameters, you can try to use the "if" condition:

```
- ${{ if eq(parameters.myParam, 'True') }}: 
  - script: echo true
```

Comment: Sorry but after testing, **it does not work**.
When I add the provided code (if...) at the end of my template, the step is ignore, like if the if condition is false...
I want to use the parameter, not the variable, because the template does not know the variable...

Comment: please check more about parameters: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script#use-parameters-to-determine-what-steps-run

Answer (score 0):

How about this [set-variables-in-scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts)